# I need to make this canvas transparent but none of the solutions are working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5-canvas, google-web-designer

I have tried all the jQuery tricks as well as the CSS tricks, but none of them work.. I don't really know anything about `<canvas>` but I've been trying to solve this for a day now.. can anybody help?

I am trying not mess up the code and just make the black background transparent so that I could use this canvas over a carousal..

// helper functions

```js
const PI2 = Math.PI * 2
const random = (min, max) => Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min | 0
const timestamp = _ => new Date().getTime()

// container
class Birthday {
  constructor() {
    this.resize()

    // create a lovely place to store the firework
    this.fireworks = []
    this.counter = 0

  }

  resize() {
    this.width = canvas.width = window.innerWidth
    let center = this.width / 2 | 0
    this.spawnA = center - center / 4 | 0
    this.spawnB = center + center / 4 | 0

    this.height = canvas.height = window.innerHeight
    this.spawnC = this.height * .1
    this.spawnD = this.height * .5

  }

  onClick(evt) {
    let x = evt.clientX || evt.touches && evt.touches[0].pageX
    let y = evt.clientY || evt.touches && evt.touches[0].pageY

    let count = random(3, 5)
    for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) this.fireworks.push(new Firework(
      random(this.spawnA, this.spawnB),
      this.height,
      x,
      y,
      random(0, 260),
      random(30, 110)))

    this.counter = -1

  }

  update(delta) {
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'hard-light'
    ctx.fillStyle = `rgba(20,20,20,${ 7 * delta })`
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height)

    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'lighter'
    for (let firework of this.fireworks) firework.update(delta)

    // if enough time passed... create new new firework
    this.counter += delta * 3 // each second
    if (this.counter >= 1) {
      this.fireworks.push(new Firework(
        random(this.spawnA, this.spawnB),
        this.height,
        random(0, this.width),
        random(this.spawnC, this.spawnD),
        random(0, 360),
        random(30, 110)))
      this.counter = 0
    }

    // remove the dead fireworks
    if (this.fireworks.length > 1000) this.fireworks = this.fireworks.filter(firework => !firework.dead)

  }
}

class Firework {
  constructor(x, y, targetX, targetY, shade, offsprings) {
    this.dead = false
    this.offsprings = offsprings

    this.x = x
    this.y = y
    this.targetX = targetX
    this.targetY = targetY

    this.shade = shade
    this.history = []
  }
  update(delta) {
    if (this.dead) return

    let xDiff = this.targetX - this.x
    let yDiff = this.targetY - this.y
    if (Math.abs(xDiff) > 3 || Math.abs(yDiff) > 3) { // is still moving
      this.x += xDiff * 2 * delta
      this.y += yDiff * 2 * delta

      this.history.push({
        x: this.x,
        y: this.y
      })

      if (this.history.length > 20) this.history.shift()

    } else {
      if (this.offsprings && !this.madeChilds) {

        let babies = this.offsprings / 2
        for (let i = 0; i < babies; i++) {
          let targetX = this.x + this.offsprings * Math.cos(PI2 * i / babies) | 0
          let targetY = this.y + this.offsprings * Math.sin(PI2 * i / babies) | 0

          birthday.fireworks.push(new Firework(this.x, this.y, targetX, targetY, this.shade, 0))

        }

      }
      this.madeChilds = true
      this.history.shift()
    }

    if (this.history.length === 0) this.dead = true
    else if (this.offsprings) {
      for (let i = 0; this.history.length > i; i++) {
        let point = this.history[i]
        ctx.beginPath()
        ctx.fillStyle = 'hsl(' + this.shade + ',100%,' + i + '%)'
        ctx.arc(point.x, point.y, 1, 0, PI2, false)
        ctx.fill()
      }
    } else {
      ctx.beginPath()
      ctx.fillStyle = 'hsl(' + this.shade + ',100%,50%)'
      ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, 1, 0, PI2, false)
      ctx.fill()
    }

  }
}

let canvas = document.getElementById('birthday')
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

let then = timestamp()

let birthday = new Birthday
window.onresize = () => birthday.resize()
document.onclick = evt => birthday.onClick(evt)
document.ontouchstart = evt => birthday.onClick(evt)

;
(function loop() {
  requestAnimationFrame(loop)

  let now = timestamp()
  let delta = now - then

  then = now
  birthday.update(delta / 1000)


})()
```

```html
<canvas id="birthday"></canvas>
```

Comment: Comment out this line: `ctx.fillRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height)`

Comment: sorry that didn't work..

Comment: Sorry for the weird question, this is a learning experience for me as i'm realtively new to canvas, but in this line: `ctx.fillStyle = `rgba(20,20,20,${ 7 * delta })``, why is your alpha value described as `${ 7 * delta }`? Is this for something you're trying to accomplish? Try setting it to 0, or 0.1 and see if anything works. If this is a stupid suggestion based on my inexperience, please disregard.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett I believe that's used to slowly fade the background in when the animation first starts.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is replace `fillRect` with `clearRect` in the `update` method of the `Birthday` class like this:

```
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height)
```

You may need to make further adjustments to the color of the firework trail though, since it seems like it was supposed to match the background color.

If your canvas still isn't transparent, check your css to ensure that you're not setting the background color that way.

```js
const PI2 = Math.PI * 2
const random = (min, max) => Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min | 0
const timestamp = _ => new Date().getTime()

// container
class Birthday {
  constructor() {
    this.resize()

    // create a lovely place to store the firework
    this.fireworks = []
    this.counter = 0

  }

  resize() {
    this.width = canvas.width = window.innerWidth
    let center = this.width / 2 | 0
    this.spawnA = center - center / 4 | 0
    this.spawnB = center + center / 4 | 0

    this.height = canvas.height = window.innerHeight
    this.spawnC = this.height * .1
    this.spawnD = this.height * .5

  }

  onClick(evt) {
    let x = evt.clientX || evt.touches && evt.touches[0].pageX
    let y = evt.clientY || evt.touches && evt.touches[0].pageY

    let count = random(3, 5)
    for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) this.fireworks.push(new Firework(
      random(this.spawnA, this.spawnB),
      this.height,
      x,
      y,
      random(0, 260),
      random(30, 110)))

    this.counter = -1

  }

  update(delta) {
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'hard-light'
    ctx.fillStyle = `rgba(20,20,20,${ 7 * delta })`
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height)

    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'lighter'
    for (let firework of this.fireworks) firework.update(delta)

    // if enough time passed... create new new firework
    this.counter += delta * 3 // each second
    if (this.counter >= 1) {
      this.fireworks.push(new Firework(
        random(this.spawnA, this.spawnB),
        this.height,
        random(0, this.width),
        random(this.spawnC, this.spawnD),
        random(0, 360),
        random(30, 110)))
      this.counter = 0
    }

    // remove the dead fireworks
    if (this.fireworks.length > 1000) this.fireworks = this.fireworks.filter(firework => !firework.dead)

  }
}

class Firework {
  constructor(x, y, targetX, targetY, shade, offsprings) {
    this.dead = false
    this.offsprings = offsprings

    this.x = x
    this.y = y
    this.targetX = targetX
    this.targetY = targetY

    this.shade = shade
    this.history = []
  }
  update(delta) {
    if (this.dead) return

    let xDiff = this.targetX - this.x
    let yDiff = this.targetY - this.y
    if (Math.abs(xDiff) > 3 || Math.abs(yDiff) > 3) { // is still moving
      this.x += xDiff * 2 * delta
      this.y += yDiff * 2 * delta

      this.history.push({
        x: this.x,
        y: this.y
      })

      if (this.history.length > 20) this.history.shift()

    } else {
      if (this.offsprings && !this.madeChilds) {

        let babies = this.offsprings / 2
        for (let i = 0; i < babies; i++) {
          let targetX = this.x + this.offsprings * Math.cos(PI2 * i / babies) | 0
          let targetY = this.y + this.offsprings * Math.sin(PI2 * i / babies) | 0

          birthday.fireworks.push(new Firework(this.x, this.y, targetX, targetY, this.shade, 0))

        }

      }
      this.madeChilds = true
      this.history.shift()
    }

    if (this.history.length === 0) this.dead = true
    else if (this.offsprings) {
      for (let i = 0; this.history.length > i; i++) {
        let point = this.history[i]
        ctx.beginPath()
        ctx.fillStyle = 'hsl(' + this.shade + ',100%,' + i + '%)'
        ctx.arc(point.x, point.y, 1, 0, PI2, false)
        ctx.fill()
      }
    } else {
      ctx.beginPath()
      ctx.fillStyle = 'hsl(' + this.shade + ',100%,50%)'
      ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, 1, 0, PI2, false)
      ctx.fill()
    }

  }
}

let canvas = document.getElementById('birthday')
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

let then = timestamp()

let birthday = new Birthday
window.onresize = () => birthday.resize()
document.onclick = evt => birthday.onClick(evt)
document.ontouchstart = evt => birthday.onClick(evt)

;
(function loop() {
  requestAnimationFrame(loop)

  let now = timestamp()
  let delta = now - then

  then = now
  birthday.update(delta / 1000)


})()
```

```css
div {
 height : 100vh;
 width : 100vw;
 display : flex;
 flex-direction : center;
 align-items : center;
 justify-content : center;
}

canvas {
  position : absolute;
  top : 0;
  left : 0;
}
```

```html
<div>Content Underneath</div>
<canvas id="birthday"></canvas>
```